# Brownie v1.18.1 - testing for onlyOwner method resulting in failed test (ValueError: Gas estimation failed), need exceptions.VirtualMachineError

Tags: solidity, python, brownie

I am going through the excellent tutorial here https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?t=21222

at the linked timestamp, the brownie test calling an OnlyOwner from a non valid address resulted in Brownie.Exceptions.VirtualMachineError.

However in my terminal it results in

`fund_me.withdraw({"from": bad_actor}) E           ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.`

So my test failed on this. I am running brownie v1.18.1

Hope I can get some help here. Thank you in advance!

Edit:
Code added

test code

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account, LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT
from scripts.testDeploy import deploy_fund_me
from brownie import network, accounts, exceptions
import pytest

def test_fund_and_withdraw():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = deploy_fund_me()
    entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee()
    tx = fund_me.fund({"from": account, "value": entrance_fee})
    tx.wait(1)
    assert fund_me.addressToAmountFunded(account.address) == entrance_fee
    tx2 = fund_me.withdraw({"from": account})
    tx2.wait(1)
    assert fund_me.addressToAmountFunded(account.address) == 0  

def test_only_owner_can_withdraw():
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT:
        pytest.skip("only for local env")
    fund_me = deploy_fund_me()
    bad_actor = accounts.add()
    with pytest.raises(exceptions.VirtualMachineError):
        fund_me.withdraw({"from": bad_actor})
```

helpful_scripts.py

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
from web3 import Web3
from brownie import network, config, accounts, MockV3Aggregator

DECIMALS = 8
STARTING_PRICE = 200000000000
FORKED_ENVIRONMENT = ["mainnet-for-dev"]
LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT = ["development", "ganache_local"]

def get_account():
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT 
        or network.show_active() in FORKED_ENVIRONMENT
    ):
        return accounts[0]
    else: 
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])

def deploy_mock():
    if len(MockV3Aggregator) >= 0:
        print(f"the active network is {network.show_active()}")
        print("Deploying mocks....")
        MockV3Aggregator.deploy(
            DECIMALS, STARTING_PRICE, {"from": get_account()}
        )
        print("Mock deployed")
```

testDeploy.py

```
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, config, network
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    get_account, 
    deploy_mock, 
    LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT
)

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT:
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][
            "price_feed"
        ]
    else:
        deploy_mock() 
        price_feed_address = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address, 
        {"from": account}, 
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")
    return(fund_me)

def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Comment: Hi, it's pretty hard to answer this without seeing your full code and tests. Could you please add them?

Comment: just added the code :)

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Could you also confirm what version of Solidity you're running. I just tested this with 0.6.6 and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using 0.6.12 on my brownie config